# How to align h2 and p on same basline in div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a post header `div` with height of 70px/4.375em
In it is a category `h2` and a `p` timestamp

I want it to be aligned as demonstrated in [this picture](http://puu.sh/eFNsp/3bb8967fa7.png) 
(made in Photoshop)

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="post-header" style="background-color:#9377d8">
    <h2 class="category">Technology</h2>
    <p class="timestamp">Saturday, today</p>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.post-header{
    height:4.375em;
    width:25em;
    margin-bottom:0;
    float:left;
}
.category{
    color:white;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin:0.625em;
}

.timestamp{
    color:white;
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    margin:0.625em;
}
```

Please help me with the CSS to get the design that I want

Comment: Floats kill vertical-alignment. @Devin's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your CSS as follows:

```
.post-header {
    height:4.375em;
    width:25em;
    margin-bottom:0;
    display:block;
}
.category {
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    width:45%;
    margin:0.625em;
}
.timestamp {
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:right;
    margin:0.625em;
    width:40%;
}
```

This way, you get better control over your layout since you can specify both the width and the vertical align of the element. As we're at it, I'd use percentages for margins, but of course it goes on you

[Visit fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22hpfgts/) to see it in action

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following.  Instead of floats, use inline-blocks with `text-align: justify`.

This only works if there at least two lines of text, so generate an extra blank line with the pseudo-element `.post-header:after`.

```css
.post-header {
  height: 4.375em;
  width: 25em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  float: left;
  text-align: justify;
}
.category {
  color: white;
  margin: 0.625em;
  display: inline-block;
}
.timestamp {
  color: white;
  margin: 0.625em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right; 
}
.post-header:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-header" style="background-color:#9377d8">
  <h2 class="category">Technology</h2>
  <p class="timestamp">Saturday, today</p>
</div>
```